# How to create a deb package that adds ppa then installs another package?

Tags: installation, ppa, deb

I'm looking for a single click solution to add a ppa then install a package in that ppa as the apturl method is disabled for security reasons.

I'm wanting to create a .deb file that adds my ppa then installs a package (another.deb) from my ppa. All in one step. Similar to the way that GetDeb/PlayDeb has a repository add .deb etc.

Comment: What do mean by apturl method? Do you mean to say add-apt-repository is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to add repositories via the Software Source Menu (Ubuntu Software Center -> Edit -> software sources -> other software -> add)? If were are able to, then you would perform "sudo apt-get update" to update your repo information. Then after that, just type in `sudo apt-get install 'package name'`(be as specific as possible as apt-get is very finicky)